# How can I write a method that turns a sheet of data into records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to gather data and then write a method to generate records based on said data. After running the method, I want to have a series of Movies and MovieRelations (which associates similar movies with each other). Each Movie will have a `title`, `release_date`, and several similar Movies through a MovieRelation. Each MovieRelation will have a `movie_a_id` and a `movie_b_id`.

The simplest way I've come up with would be to write a text document with the movies and their individual data separated by two different special symbols, to mark where the text should be broken up into separate movies, and where the movies should be broken up into their individual pieces of data, like this:

```
Title@Release Date@Similar Movie A@Similar Movie B%Title2@Release Date2@Similar Movie 2A@Similar Movie 2B@Similar Movie 2C
```

Then I could copy and paste the raw text into a method similar to this:

```
"X Men@11-02-2010@Hulk@Logan%Sing@12-04-2017@Zootopia@Pitch Perfect@Monster U"
.split('%').map.each do |movie_data|
  @movie = Movie.create()
  movie_data.split('@').map.each_with_index do |individual_data, index|
    if index == 1
      @movie.name = individual_data
    elsif index == 2
      @movie.release_date = individual_data
    elsif index > 2
      MovieRelation.create(movie_a_id: @movie.id, movie_b_id: Movie.find_by(name: individual_data))
    end
  end
  @movie.save
end
```

So in the end, I should have 2 Movies and 5 MovieRelations.

I think this would work, but it seems pretty hacky. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you able to generate a JSON document instead to add some better structure to your data? the '@' delimited document is probably going to cause you headaches in the long run.

Comment: It looks like you could use a `case` statement there to break out your conditions, it saves a lot of fuss. Also why not use a well-defined data format like JSON or CSV rather than inventing your own wonky format that's bound to fail on edge cases like movies with `@` in the title. Also don't forget you should omit empty argument lists: `Movie.create` is sufficient.

Comment: +1 for JSON or CSV.
With CSV its as easy as `CSV.parse(string, :col_sep => "@")` which returns the same `.split` array. Not really much different than what you are doing, but it looks nicer. In any case `@` delimiting is probably not safe as mentioned above

Comment: Another vote for CSV. There is a chicken/egg problem with your logic, though. You won't be able to create a movie relation until the related movie has been added. If “X Men” is the first row of data in your dataset then it will fail on MovieRelation.create because it can’t find “Hulk”. But if you put the “Hulk” row ahead of “X Men” then whatever movie it’s related to would have to be before “Hulk”. And so on and so on.

Another option would be to have two datasets. The first imports only the titles and dates. The second contains a list of related movies.

Comment: Don't invent a new way to represent the data as text, instead use an existing format so you can take advantage of existing wheels. YAML and JSON are great starting points. If you're generating the data by hand then YAML is more readable but it's not as compact. Ruby comes with both serializers/parsers so it's easy to read/generate the data on the fly. CSV is old-school and won't allow you to represent relational information that JSON and YAML will do if you treat it as embedded hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start trying to create your own format, I'd suggest looking at YAML or JSON, which are well established, well supported, are internet standards with established syntax, and have parsers/serializers for the major languages so your data won't be locked to just your application.

Here's a starting point:

```
require 'yaml'

data = {
  'title' => 'Raiders of the Lost Ark',
  'release_date' => '12 June 1981',
  'similar_movies' => [
    {
      'title' => 'Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade',
      'release_date' => '24 May 1989',
      'similar_movies' => nil
    },
    {
      'title' => 'Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom',
      'release_date' => '23 May 1984',
      'similar_movies' => nil
    }
  ]
}

puts data.to_yaml
```

That outputs:

```
---
title: Raiders of the Lost Ark
release_date: 12 June 1981
similar_movies:
- title: Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade
  release_date: 24 May 1989
  similar_movies: 
- title: Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom
  release_date: 23 May 1984
  similar_movies:
```

YAML is parsed using the [Psych](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html) class so see the Psych documentation's [`load`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load), [`load_file`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_file) and maybe [`load_stream`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_stream) methods to learn how to read that data and convert it back to a Ruby object.

Similarly you could use JSON:

```
require 'json'

puts data.to_json
```

Which outputs:

```
{"title":"Raiders of the Lost Ark","release_date":"12 June 1981","similar_movies":[{"title":"Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade","release_date":"24 May 1989","similar_movies":null},{"title":"Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom","release_date":"23 May 1984","similar_movies":null}]}
```

Or, if you need "pretty":

```
puts JSON.pretty_generate(data)

{
  "title": "Raiders of the Lost Ark",
  "release_date": "12 June 1981",
  "similar_movies": [
    {
      "title": "Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade",
      "release_date": "24 May 1989",
      "similar_movies": null
    },
    {
      "title": "Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom",
      "release_date": "23 May 1984",
      "similar_movies": null
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON lets us use `JSON['some JSON as a string']` or `JSON[a_ruby_hash_or_array]` as a shortcut to parse or serialize respectively:

```
foo = JSON[{'a' => 1}]
foo # => "{\"a\":1}"
JSON[foo] # => {"a"=>1}
```

In either case, experiment with using Ruby to build your starting hash and let it emit the serialized version, then pipe that output to a file and begin filling it in.

If you want to use an ID for a related movie instead of the name you'll have to order your records in the file so the related movies occur first, remember what those IDs are after inserting them, then plug them into your data. That's really a pain. Instead, I'd walk through the object that results from parsing the data, extract all the related movies, insert them, then insert the main record. How to do that is left for you to figure out, but it's not too hard.

Answer (score 0):

## Parsing the string

For your code, you don't need an index, `if` or `case` but just split and splat :

```
input = 'X Men@11-02-2010@Hulk@Logan%Sing@12-04-2017@Zootopia@Pitch Perfect@Monster U'

input.split('%').each do |movie_data|
  title, date, *related_movies = movie_data.split('@')
  puts format('%-10s (%s) Related : %s', title, date, related_movies)
end
```

It outputs :

```
X Men      (11-02-2010) Related : ["Hulk", "Logan"]
Sing       (12-04-2017) Related : ["Zootopia", "Pitch Perfect", "Monster U"]
```

## Saving data

You're trying to solve a problem that has already been solved. `MovieRelations` belong to, well, a relational database!

You could do all the imports, sorts and filters with a database (e.g. with Rails or Sequel). Once you're done and would like to export the information as plain text, you could dump your data into YAML/SQL/JSON.

With your current format, you'll only run into problems when you want to update relations, delete a movie or insert a movie with `%` or `@` in the [title](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1492721/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).